# Relation function between surfaces, what to read?

Tags: geometry, functions, surfaces

Suppose I have two continuous surfaces A and B. I want to define the function f which will link the surfaces like A = f(B), i.e. when B changing then A also will changes in the way defined by f and vice versa. Especially interesting case that look like A = f(B,Θ) where parameter Θ define how exactly surfaces A and B linked.

Where/what can I read about this and stuff around? If you faced similar problem please share something about.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for related field differential geometry mostly study things related to surfaces and their parametrizations.The problem is that it is still unclear what exactly do you want to achieve (because as you wrote in Russian you want to represent and work with continuous surfaces as arrays of points which is impossible -- they have continual number of them!). So as already been suggest at dxdy.ru you may start with reading introductory parts of surfaces theory from calculus books or straight away look through basics of differential geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am very newbie in this field, so may talk unclear, sorry. 
The main goal is actually to build the function f, which can generally transform A to B and vice versa (in my imagination it look like «we put B and Θ into black box which will produce new A then»). Therefore, I search what I can learn to solve this.
Yes, I was wrong, the array like represention is impossible, surfaces need to be continuous.